# Is it a good idea to separate the guest_uuid field to a mapping table

Tags: mysql, refactoring

The client create a new uuid value to generate and identify a new guest account, and the guest uuid value is now stored in the 'account' table.

'account' table schema: account_id, guest_uuid, other_fields.

guest_uuid is null if the account is not a guest, for example, sign in by facebook.

guest_uuid is only used to check is the account exists. sign in if exists or generate a new guest account if not exists.

Is it a good idea to separate the guest_uuid field from table account to a mapping table called guest_account(guest_uuid, account_id)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to separate the guest_uuid field from table account to a mapping table?

Probably not. UUIDs are small enough to be contained with rows. (They don't require storage external to the row like `TEXT` data types do.) It's not worth the complexity of building and maintaining a new table.

An exception:  If each `account_id` in your application can have multiple uuids, you need this extra table.

Another exception: If you already have millions of rows in your account table, and you are *adding* functionality requiring this uuid, adding a table may be easier than modifying your account table.  Talk to the person who maintains your MySQL server and data.